# How to extract e-mail from string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'd like to extract e-mail from string.
I have the string `abc defg email@email.com` and I would like to get the string `email@email.com`.

How could I do it in PL / SQL?

Comment: Check this out http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/189919/

Comment: Will the email always be last?

Comment: You could try searching the string for the character return for @ passing its Len as an in of the blank space and then grabbing the ngram token of that int in the full sting. Its a pain but doable and will aways be consostant. Do you have a data sample ?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in PL/SQL? In most cases if you can do something in straight SQL it will be more efficient than through PL/SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work for many situations, but is far from perfect. I added one string that demonstrates two different ways in which this may fail, you will notice them. It will not be easy to write a query that catches ALL possible situations; how far you take the further refinement of the "match pattern" depends on how out-of-the-ordinary the emails in your input data may be.

In the regular expression, note that the dot (.) must be escaped with a backslash, and within matching lists (lists of characters in square brackets) the hyphen - must be either the first or the last characters in the list, anywhere else it is a metacharacter.

In the output, notice the last row; the input string is empty, so the output is null as well.

```
with
     input_strings ( str ) as (
       select 'sdss abc@gmail.com sdsda sdsds  '            from dual union all
       select 'pele@1-futbol.br may not work'               from dual union all
       select 'sql@oracle.com, sam@att.net,solo@violin.com' from dual union all
       select ''                                            from dual union all
       select 'this string contains no email addresses'     from dual union all
       select '-this:email@address.illegal_domain'          from dual union all
       select 'alpha@123.34.23.1 talk@radio@mike.com'       from dual
     )
select str   as original_string,
       level as idx,
       regexp_substr(str, '[[:alnum:]_-]+@[[:alnum:]_-]+\.[[:alnum:]_-]+', 1, level) 
                                                                      as email_address
from   input_strings
connect by regexp_substr(str, '[[:alnum:]_-]+@[[:alnum:]_-]+\.[[:alnum:]_-]+', 1, level)
                                                                              is not null
    and prior str = str 
    and prior sys_guid() is not null
;

ORIGINAL_STRING                                    IDX EMAIL_ADDRESS
------------------------------------------- ---------- --------------------------------
-this:email@address.illegal_domain                   1 email@address.illegal_domain
alpha@123.34.23.1 talk@radio@mike.com                1 alpha@123.34
alpha@123.34.23.1 talk@radio@mike.com                2 radio@mike.com
pele@1-futbol.br may not work                        1 pele@1-futbol.br
sdss abc@gmail.com sdsda sdsds                       1 abc@gmail.com
sql@oracle.com, sam@att.net,solo@violin.com          1 sql@oracle.com
sql@oracle.com, sam@att.net,solo@violin.com          2 sam@att.net
sql@oracle.com, sam@att.net,solo@violin.com          3 solo@violin.com
this string contains no email addresses              1
                                                     1

10 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm)) :

```
select regexp_substr ('sdss abc@gmail.com sdsda sdsds  ','[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}') email from dual
```